# Nested resourse link error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, link-to

I have some trouble. 
I have 3 models : Forum Topic Post
Forum

```
 has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy
```

Topic

```
  belongs_to :forum
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

Post belongs_to :topic

Forum controller

```
class ForumsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @forums = Forum.all
end

def show
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  @topics = Topic.all
end

end
```

Topic controller

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @topic = @forum.topics.create(topic_params)
    if @topic.save
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def new
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @topic = Topic.new
end

def show
@forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
@topics = Topic.find(params[:id])

end

private
def topic_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :created_at, :last_poster_id => current_user.id, :last_post_at => Time.now)
end
```

end

```
 routes.rb 
 resources :forums do
  resources :topics
 end
```

forum/show

```
- @forum.topics.each do |f|


= link_to f.name, forum_topic_path[@forum, @topic]




 rake routes:
   forum_topics GET    /forums/:forum_id/topics(.:format)                  topics#index
                         POST   /forums/:forum_id/topics(.:format)                  topics#create
         new_forum_topic GET    /forums/:forum_id/topics/new(.:format)              topics#new
        edit_forum_topic GET    /forums/:forum_id/topics/:id/edit(.:format)         topics#edit
             forum_topic GET    /forums/:forum_id/topics/:id(.:format)              topics#show
                         PATCH  /forums/:forum_id/topics/:id(.:format)              topics#update
                         PUT    /forums/:forum_id/topics/:id(.:format)              topics#update
                         DELETE /forums/:forum_id/topics/:id(.:format)              topics#destroy
                  forums GET    /forums(.:format)                                   forums#index
                         POST   /forums(.:format)                                   forums#create
               new_forum GET    /forums/new(.:format)                               forums#new
              edit_forum GET    /forums/:id/edit(.:format)                          forums#edit
                   forum GET    /forums/:id(.:format)                               forums#show
                         PATCH  /forums/:id(.:format)                               forums#update
                         PUT    /forums/:id(.:format)                               forums#update
                         DELETE /forums/:id(.:format)                               forums#destroy
```

but i have error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"topics", :id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:forum_id]
```

idn how to create this is nested links... help me

Comment: Can you please post contents to your routes.rb file ? 
Also if you could paste the output of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to get it working:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :forums do
   resources :topics
end

#app/models/forum.rb
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :topics
end

#app/models/topic.rb
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :forum
end

#app/controllers/forums_controller.rb
class ForumsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @forum  = Forum.find params[:id]
      @topics = @forum.topics
   end
end

#app/views/forums/show.html.erb #-> url.com/forums/5
<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    = link_to topic.name, forum_topic_path(@forum.id, topic.id)
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your main issue was that you were not using `@forum.id` and `topic.id` in your link. However, `@topics = Topic.all` was not valid either

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
resources :forums do
   resources :topics
end
```

and in view

```
- @topics.each do |f|
  = link_to f.name, forum_topic_path(f.forum.id, f.id)
```

and in controller

```
def show
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  @topics = @forum.topics

end
```